# codeIgniter mongoDB delete document not work with id

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

This is not working:

```
function delmodel()
{
   $this->mongo_db->where->(array('_id'=>'5195b4293f8f31362a4f2093'))->delete('links');
}
```

This is working:

```
function delmodel()
{
    $this->mongo_db->where->(array('url'=>'www.google.com'))->delete('links');
}
```

I am working with CodeIgniter MongoDB and I'm totaly baffled with my output.

Comment: i am not working with codeigniter and whatever library you are using so this may be a stupid question, but doesnt mongo need the id as an MongoID Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following

```
function delmodel()
{
   $id = new MongoId('5195b4293f8f31362a4f2093');
   $this->mongo_db->where->(array('_id'=> $id))->delete('links');
}
```